# Java conversion Integer to String inconsistency

Tags: java, arrays

Why does conversion from collection of Integers to collection of String work but it fails when I actually has to convert the Integer to String?
Why dosent it fail/catch it earlier? 
In my example below

```
static <T extends List<?> >
    void testConversion(T... args)
    {
        **// Didnt catch here?**
        List<String>[] slarray = (List<String>[])args;
        System.out.printf("Value is %s\n", slarray[0].get(0));
        **// Didnt catch here?**
        List<String> slist = (List<String>)args[0];
        // FAIL runtime exception
        String s2 = slist.get(0);
        // FAIL exception
        String s = slarray[0].get(0); 
    }

public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        testConversion(Arrays.asList(11,12), Arrays.asList(21,22));
    }
```

Comment: Because you're not doing any conversion there. Just doing an unsafe type cast of references..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Java Generics are a compile time thing, and the actual type is erased when the program runs.

You defined your `T` as a "List of whatever". You then cast a reference to a "List of whatever" to a "List of String". It may be possible that this type cast will work (thus, it is not a compile-time error), and so the compiler doesn't complain, but leaves the issue to the run-time system.

In run time, it's just a reference to a `List`. So the run time environment doesn't complain either - you cast an array of `List` and assign it to an array of `List`, and the actual type is erased at this point.

But when it comes to getting the actual values, the run time environment can see that the value cannot actually be assigned to a String, and so it throws an exception.

Comment: I knew the compile part. But at runtime its not a List of whatever. I get it now - because its just blindly assigning the reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you provide a cast in your code, you are telling the compiler, "I know you have an instance of *x*, but I know it's really a *y*.  Treat it as a *y*."  If the cast is possible at all, then the compiler will allow it.

You are telling the compiler that `args`, which it knows is a `T[]`, can be cast to a `List<String>[]`.  You are also telling the compiler that `args[0]`, which it accepts to be a `T`, is a `List<String>`.

It happens here that when calling `testConversion`, you are passing `List<Integer>`s.  The type `T` is inferred to be `Integer`.  However, because of type erasure, at runtime, they are really `List`s.  Also, the cast to `List<String>[]` and `List<String>` succeed, because at runtime, they are really casts to `List[]` and `List`, respectively.

When you compiled, you should have received an unchecked cast warning about casting to `List<String>[]` and to `List<String>`.  It was warning you about type safety.  It also inserted a cast to `String` on the call to `get`, because you told it that it was a `List<String>`.  When you finally attempted to get a `String` out your `List<String>`, the JVM threw a runtime exception because the element really was an `Integer`.

When you casted `args` to a `List<String>[]`, and when you casted `args[0]` to a `List<String>`, you lied to the compiler, but the JVM caught your lie.